# Android Volley JsonObjectRequest Handle HTTP response status code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am sending  http post request with json data to server. When i return status code 201 on server volley throws an error.

What i am trying to do is send jsonobjectrequest to server, and when i recieve http status code 201 handle that on response.
The error is

```
 ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Created of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is the code:

```
val sendFirebaseTokenRequest = object: JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, tokenData,
                Response.Listener<JSONObject> { response ->

                   //this is not called since i return sendStatus(201) on server.i dont return json.






                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->

               //this is called because i return http status 201


                }
        )  {


            override  fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = tokenStorage.getAccessToken()
                return headers
            }


        }
```

There are some similar questions on stackoverflow but all answers are outdated.Looks like i should override something but couldnt manage. I also tried to create some custom request classses but shared code on stackoverflow was outdated and not working.

Answer (score -1):

try changing `Response.Listener<JSONObject>` to `Response.Listener<String>` it should normally go into success.

You should check if your response of 201 is in JSON mode and not plaintext. Could you post the JSON response you're getting ?

If you want your 201 request to go into your success you should at least put a json such as :

```
{
  "message": "The item was created successfully"
}
```

Comment: thats the thing. i wanna send json but i wanna recieve status code 201 not json

Comment: Could you explain more ? You want to receive a JSON but not when you get a 201 response ?

Comment: all i want is to recieve http status code 201 and nothing else... just 201 no json just 201 return res.sendStatus(201)       and volley shouldnt throw error. ofc i know returning json from server but i dont want